# Can I have a "write once run forever" kind of system in Java?

Tags: java, osgi

I understand that OSGi modules can be added and removed dynamically during runtime. So is it possible to have a system where I can upgrade it without having to ever take it down? (Thinking along the line of Erlang/OTP, but let's say I don't require the fault-tolerant guarantees of an Erlang system). If not what is the blocking factor? Currently, I am looking into OSGi, but have not digged deeper.

Footnote
The "write once, run forever" is from Joe Armstrong on Erlang.

Comment: I think you'd better forget it with Java and its palette of common resource leaks. OSGi's modularity requires that all the module's clients are well-behaved in non-trivial ways; in other words, it's just another fragile, cooperative mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm tempted to say **Jain** which some of my former colleagues used. It is the fusion of *Ja* and *Nein*. Basically in theory you can do it but in practice you can't.

So you should either use Erlang or forget about the concept.

There are a lot of places where it can go wrong. For example if you plan to deploy your app with Tomcat it is famous of its resource leaks. It simply can't run forever.

Comment: And Tomcat is just the one being honest about it because *all* the JEE containers share exactly the same issues.

Comment: And we haven't even started talking about server applications.

Comment: Accepted this answer, but I not dismissing the idea completely. Forget about Tomcat. Let's assume a custom built one with NIO.2 with quality code. I think that can make leaking minimal. I don't think JVM as such has resource leaking issue. It's poor application code that makes it so. No?

Comment: Yea I agree for some degree but I'm not that involved in the implementation details of the JVM to provide an authoriative answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, OSGi is your answer.

But if you don't need the highest fault-tolerance, what is a "write once, run forever" good for? You induce a lot of constraints for the architecture right in the beginning.

Which kind of components do you want to have replaceable during runtime?

Edit: OSGi is more than 13yrs old and not yet 'common sense' or widely used.

Comment: Module upgrades with new functionality is what I have in mind at present.

Comment: Adam Arold: Yup! Fault tolerant, distributed, concurrent, neural networks, an evolving AI system. ;)

Comment: If you want to go with the JVM and do not go low level, then OSGi is a standard way to upgrade modules. 
@Adam Arold: Still searching for it. But when we unite, we can't be defeated... muhahahaha...

Comment: @kadaj: If you don't joke about an evolving AI system, you think about, check out other languages, like clojure. There you can modify the program during runtime... and it's running in the jvm. Check out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074781/editing-programs-while-they-are-running-why

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Run Forever idea is that it assumes nothing will ever go wrong, and you and no one else will ever make a mistake.  In the real world mistakes are made. You are better off developing a system which allows for such things as operator error.

If you are providing a service, allow for it to go down and start up again with redundancy or maintenance windows.  Even if upgrade software using OGSi it is still down for a very short amount of time to perform the switch, assuming it works every time (i.e. you didn't introduce a bug which prevents it)

OSGi can be very helpful when it works, but it adds an overhead to all your development processes which you need to allow for.  It is not ideal for rapid development environments. IMHO.

Comment: Disagree with your final point. OSGi in my experience removes overhead and explicitly enables a rapid development environment because of its ability to dynamically reload modules. This is as useful in development as it is in production. We use this capability in [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org) to enable a very rapid code/test/run cycle.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I am comparing this to being able to press Run/Debug/Profile from your IDE.  Perhaps with the right plugins it can be just as easy but I find there is many more things you have to think about in an OSGi application you just wouldn't worry about in a core Java application.

Comment: Such as? Conversely there are many things you would have to think about in a conventional Java app that you just wouldn't worry about in OSGi. "How do ensure my dependencies are present and compatible?" "How do I get an instance of this interface at runtime?" etc...

Comment: To the first question, you deploy the version you built and tested with, to the second question, you can use a library like "reflections" on google code, but this is something OSGi does much better.